# Android Log cannot resolve

Tags: java, android

I have this line in my android class but not inside an method.

```
Log.v("Scan Class", "Excecuted");
```

on the letter v following the period I recieve an error "Cannot resolve symbol 'v'". I have imported android.util.log; and am not sure what is creating this error. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not inside a method?  What behavior are you expecting, then?  Code example would be useful.

Comment: Show some code. what does "in android class but not inside an method" actually mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [static initializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7):

```
static 
{
    Log.v("Scan Class", "Excecuted");
}
```

This will print when your class is loaded. Classes within your app will generally be loaded as Android starts your application.

Comment: Thanks that worked out, I realize I could put it in onCreate  or other method as others have stated, however I needed this specific log to be independent from life cycle methods and rather be related to the loading of a class. Sorry for any confusion due to lack of code samples.

Answer (score 0):

You can put **Log** on below stages:

on **onCreate()**:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Log.v("Scan Class", "Excecuted");

       // Other stuff
}
```

In **method**:

```
private void checkLog(){
    Log.v("Scan Class", "Excecuted");
}
```

In **function**:

```
private String funcStr(){
    Log.v("Scan Class", "Excecuted");
    return "test";
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a method .But to call method here you need to add it in `constructor` or `static block` or `onCreate` of activity or something like that . This is because it should have some starting point like in Java  we have `main` method as stating point .